# Show that $Q^+$ is not isomorphic to $Q^* $.

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $Q^+$ be the group of positive rational numbers under multiplication.

Let $Q^*$ be the group of all the rational number of the form $\frac{p}{q}$, where both $p$ and $q$ are odd positive integers, under multiplication.

Show that $Q^+$ is not isomorphic to $Q^*$.

Comment: I think that they are isomorphic, they are both free abelian groups of rank $\aleph_0$.

Comment: @Rupert do you plan on writing an answer to that effect?

Comment: Where is the difference between $Q^+$ and $Q^*$?

Comment: @user218931 read carefully.  For example, $2 \in Q^+\setminus Q^*$

Comment: Ah, thank you. I didn't read the "odd" part :)

Comment: @hardmath : it is not a duplicate of this question. Here $Q^∗ = \{p/q \mid p,q \text{ odd positive integers} \}$ and $Q^+ = (\Bbb Q_{>0},\cdot)$.

Answer (score 5):

If $p_1,p_2,\ldots=2,3,\ldots$ is the sequence of primes then the $\phi$
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\phi(1)&=&1\\
\phi({p_i})&=&p_{i+1},\, \forall i\geq 1
\end{eqnarray}$$
can be extended to an isomorphism from $Q^+$ to $Q^*$. So they are isomorphic.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thank you

Comment: let $p/q=2^n ($p1/q1$) ,where  $p/q$  ∈ Q+ and  p1/q1 ∈ Q*

Consider the homomorphism that takes p/q to p1/q1. The Kernal of the above homomorphism isn't trivial but is {2^n: n ∈ Z}. Hence they cannot be isomorphic,right ?!

Comment: I mam not sure if I understand you. Your homomorphism is no injectiive, so it is not an isomorphism. But they are isomorphic if on isomorphism exist. My homomorphism is injectiv so it is an isomorphism.

Comment: If any two Groups are isomorphic then the Kernal K of the homomorphism from G to G' should be trivial, right ?!
                                                                                                                                                                 
Else G/K will be isomorphic to G'. And thus G cannot be isomorphic to G'.

Am I wrong ? Please correct me if I am.

Comment: @ShreedharBhat the kernel of your isomorphism is not trivial. the kernel of the isomorphism $\phi$ is $\{1\}$, so it is  trivial.

Comment: Yes exactly.The kernel K of the homomorphism I said is not trivial.And hence Q+/K is isomorphic to Q* and thus Q+ is not isomorphic to Q* is my argument.

Comment: If two groups G,H are isomorphic to each other,then any homomorphism from G to H should have trivial kernal,right ?

Comment: No,that is wrong. Your homomorphism and $\phi$ are a counterexample.

Comment: another counterexample: G is a group, the idendity is an isomophism because G is isomorphic to itself. The constant map that maps every element of G to the unity element 1 of G  is an homorphism that is not injective and therefore not an isomorphism of G, except if G={1}